# Angular: Manipulate variables from the template down to the class

Tags: angular

I have a little bit a problem in my template/component-design in Angular.
Lets see this easy sample.

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "test",
  template: `
    <ul *ngFor="let l of lst">
        <li *ngIf="l > 3">{{ l }}</li>
    </ul>
    The count is ...
`
})

export class TestComponent
{
  lst : Array <number> = [1, 3, 5, 9];
}
```

I have logic in my template (show all > 2).

Now at the end I like to know how many items were on the screen.

I do not like to share the logic in the template AND in the class.

One way to handle it is to put logic beside the data in the class (and only there) and use already filtered data 
INSTEAD of operating on all data and have logic in the template
Then it is easy to count it inside the class.

Is there another way - lets say to manipulate a counter-variable in the template that effects the class??
I tried it in calling a function in a {{ }} but that is not working in a right way.

Comment: if i understand well , what you want is to separate the logic and the presentation , is it ? ( in other words `ts` you want to implement the logic , in the template show the result )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in saying you should implement your business logic in your class. That's the best place and keeps your business logic in one place, offering the best separation of concerns. There's no point trying to do the alternative you're suggesting. It means jumping through hoops and complicating things unnecessarily. Doing the work in the class will always give you more control, flexibility and scalability. Best to get into this habit.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate list for your logic, which is a subset of your `lst`.
Then you can have logic in your component class, and presentation in template.

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "test",
  template: `
    <ul *ngFor="let l of otherList">
      <li>{{ l }}</li>
    </ul>
    The count is {{otherList.length}}
`
})

export class TestComponent
{
  lst : Array <number> = [1, 3, 5, 9];
  otherList:Array<number> = [];

  constructor(){
   this.doLogic();
  }

  doLogic(){
   lst.forEach(item=>{
    if(item>3){
      otherList.push(item);
    }
   });
  }

}
```